# $injector:modulerr error ng-route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to setup some basic routing, but keep on being faced with the `[$injector:modulerr]` error in the console. I have included `angular-route.js` in my application as it transpired this has now been moved into its own module. However, im still getting this error.

JS:

```
// App initialiser
var module = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);


// Routing config
module.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.
        when('/NewOrder', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/addOrder.htm',
            controller: 'addOrderController'
        }).
        when('/ShowOrders', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/showOrders.htm',
            controller: 'showOrdersController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/NewOrder'
        });

});

// Add Order Controller
module.controller('addOrderController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "This is the Add Order screen.";
});

// Show Orders Controller
module.controller('showOrdersController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "This is the Show Orders screen.";
});
```

HTML (ng-app is included on my html tag):

```
<div class="container">

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#NewOrder"> New Order </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> New Contact </a></li>
            <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Orders </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Show Contacts </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view="">

    </div>

</div>


<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-route.min.js">

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of angularjs?

Comment: i hope you are certain that they are the same version. also can you verify that the file is actually being downloaded? use the network tab on what ever inspector you use

Comment: my aplogies, just updated the CDN link to 1.3.13. Still same issue though

Comment: The script tag for angular-route is not closed. I'm not sure whether this causes the error, but it's not good.

Comment: @RemcoHaszing Missing script tag was it!. man I feel like a plonker lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script tag for angular-route must be closed.